# Why I am getting NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I tried to figure out what is my mistake but I could not find anything with my code that's called null pointer.

Here is the StackTrace (1):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at daftoor.Database.connect(Database.java:92)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.checkSignin(DoSignIn.java:86)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.processRequest(DoSignIn.java:40)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.doGet(DoSignIn.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here are the StackTrace logs (2):

```
Jul 31, 2012 4:07:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DoSignIn] in context with path [/Daftoor] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at daftoor.Database.createStatement(Database.java:105)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.checkSignin(DoSignIn.java:91)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.processRequest(DoSignIn.java:40)
    at daftoor.DoSignIn.doGet(DoSignIn.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is the error page:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    myproject.Database.createStatement(Database.java:101)
    myproject.DoSignIn.checkSignin(DoSignIn.java:91)
    myproject.DoSignIn.processRequest(DoSignIn.java:40)
    myproject.DoSignIn.doGet(DoSignIn.java:127)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
```

Here are my code:

Database class:

```
package somePackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 *
 * @author mih1406
 */
public class Database {
    private HashMap dbConfig;
    private Connection dbConnection;

    // debugging
    HttpServletRequest request;
    HttpServletResponse response;



    public Database(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respnse) {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
        setDatabaseConfig();

    }

    public void setDatabaseConfig() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        InputStream configFile;

        try {
            configFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
            config.load(configFile);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // TODO properties file not found error
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            // TODO i/o Exception
        }

        String dbHost = config.getProperty("dbHost");
        String dbPort = config.getProperty("dbPort");
        String dbUsername = config.getProperty("dbUsername");
        String dbPassword = config.getProperty("dbPassword");
        String dbName = config.getProperty("dbName");
        String dbPrefix = config.getProperty("dbPrefix");

        setDatabaseConfig(dbHost, dbPort, dbUsername, dbPassword,
                dbName, dbPrefix);
    }

    public void setDatabaseConfig(String dbHost, String dbPort, String dbUsername,
            String dbPassword, String dbName, String dbPrefix) {
        dbConfig = new HashMap();

        dbConfig.put("dbHost", dbHost);
        dbConfig.put("dbPort", dbPort);
        dbConfig.put("dbUsername", dbUsername);
        dbConfig.put("dbPassword", dbPassword);
        dbConfig.put("dbName", dbName);
        dbConfig.put("dbPrefix", dbPrefix);
    }

    public void connect() {
        String dbHost = (String)dbConfig.get("dbHost") + "/";
        String dbPort = (String)dbConfig.get("dbPort");
        String dbUsername = (String)dbConfig.get("dbUsername");
        String dbPassword = (String)dbConfig.get("dbPassword");
        String dbName = (String)dbConfig.get("dbName");
        String dbPrefix = (String)dbConfig.get("dbPrefix");

        String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/";

        try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbURL, dbPassword);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            // TODO Class Exception
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
        }
    }

    public Statement createStatement() {
        try {
            return dbConnection.createStatement();
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
            pstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
        }

        return pstmt;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            if(dbConnection.isClosed()) {
                return;
            }

            dbConnection.close();
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
        }
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbPrefix");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbName");
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbHost");
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbPort");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbUsername");
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return (String)dbConfig.get("dbPassword");
    }
}
```

DoSingin class:

```
package somePackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author mih1406
 */
@WebServlet(name = "DoSignIn", urlPatterns = {"/DoSignIn"})
public class DoSignIn extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        checkValues(request, response);
        checkSignin(request, response);

    }

    private void checkValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String adminUsername = request.getParameter("adminUsername");
        String adminPassword = request.getParameter("adminPassword");

        boolean someEmpty = false;

        if((adminUsername.equals("") || adminUsername == null)) {
            someEmpty = true;
            request.setAttribute("emptyEmail", "Required");
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("adminUsername",
                    request.getParameter("adminUsername"));
        }

        if((adminPassword.equals("") || adminPassword == null)) {
            someEmpty = true;
            request.setAttribute("emptyPassword", "Required");
        }

        if(someEmpty) {
            String url = "signin.jsp";
            forwardToPage(request, response, url);
        }
    }

    private void forwardToPage(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String url)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void checkSignin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String adminUsername = request.getParameter("adminUsername");
        String adminPassword = request.getParameter("adminPassword");

        out.println("<br />HereDBCreation!!");
        Database db = new Database(request, response);
        db.connect();
        out.println("<br />HereDBConnectionDone!!");
        String query = "SELECT adminUsername, adminPassword FROM " +
                db.getPrefix() + db.getName() + " WHERE adminUsername = '" +
                adminUsername + "' AND adminPassword = '" + adminPassword + "'";
        Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = null;
if(stmt == null)         out.println("<br />HereDBStmtDone!!");

        try {
            result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            result.beforeFirst();
            out.println("Here!!");
            if(result.next()){
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(21*60); // 21 minutes
                    session.setAttribute("JSESSIONID", adminUsername);

                    out.println("Correct!!");
            } else {
                out.println("Invalid!!");
            }
        } catch(SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
            System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

signin.jsp JSP file:

```
<%--
    Document   : login
    Created on : Jul 19, 2012, 3:36:48 PM
    Author     : mih1406
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Administration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="DoSignIn" method="get" name="adminSignInForm">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Administration<td>
                        <br />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="adminUsername">Email:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="${adminUsername}" name="adminUsername" />${emptyEmail}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="adminPassword">Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" value="" name="adminPassword" />${emptyPassword}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked" name="persistentCookie" />
                        <label for="persistentCookie">Stay signed in</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Sign in" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you get a NullPointerException you're also getting a stacktrace. The first line of the stack trace shows you where it goes wrong.

Comment: Im pretty sure `dbConnection` is null.

Comment: Where can I see the stacktrace?

Comment: `dbConnection` is null but exception is catched when object is going to be created (`Database.connect()` method). Print these stacktrace, **never** leave a catch block empty!

Comment: @jelies: I tried to print stacktrace but I could not. Using System.out.println()

Comment: @MIH1406 use `ex.printStackTrace()` where `ex` is you Exception.

Comment: you are only catching SQLException change that to Exception and print stacktrace to debug it ex.printStackTrace()

Comment: @Baz I did ex.printStackTrace() but I don't know where to look for the printed StackTrace?

Comment: @MIH1406 In the console !? Where all your output goes... (unless you redirected it manually)

Comment: You are not catching NullPointerException so it will not be printed in the console

Comment: Looks like your app is unable to find the jdbc driver and is causing your db connection to be null which is in turn causing the exception to be thrown when you attempt to create the statement. You should add a check to see if the db connection is null before attempting to create the statement. Fixing the ClassNotFoundException will probaly fix those two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Database.createStatement()`, the line:

```
return dbConnection.createStatement();
```

throws the error, which means `dbConnection` is null.

In your `connect()` method you have these lines:

```
try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbURL, dbPassword);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            // TODO Class Exception
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            // TODO SQL Exception
        }
```

So even if the connection failed you won't know about it since you do nothing in the catch block.

i suggest you change it to:

```
try {
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbURL, dbPassword);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
           cnfe.printStacktrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStacktrace();
        }
```

And i bet you'll find out that you have a problem there.

Comment: add one more catch Block for RuntimeException to catch NullPointerException and in that catch block e.printStacktrace() will trace the log in the console

Comment: you can also use : `writer.out(cnfe.getMessage());` to get only the error message.

Comment: @srikanthyaradla - it is not really needed, as he already knows where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

It's these checks

`(adminUsername.equals("") || adminUsername == null)`

Your input can come in as null, and you've accounted for that, but if it does, it will try to execute this statement first `adminUsername.equals("")` and throw an NPE. Simply invert their order, and it should solve your problem.

`( adminUsername == null || adminUsername.equals(""))`

@ftom2 is also correct, it could be the `dbConnection.createStatement();` line, but with out a stack trace we can't really tell. You should make these changes to accomodate the possibility for a null, so that the issues won't arise later.